# Solr boost direct match over fuzzy match

Tags: solr

Let's say I have a query like this:

`text_data:(Apple OR Apple~2)`

How do I know what boost value to provide to give the direct match a clear priority over the fuzzy match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really guarantee a clear priority as the fuzzy search will naturally match on more terms (Apple, Appl, App, Appla and so on). Just give it a high enough boost value that it will outscore the fuzzy search in everything but edge cases. The fuzzy search will also help you out by scoring an exact match for 'Apple' higher than any matches that have deletions or substitutions

```
text_data:(Apple^10 OR Apple~2)
```

Will multiply 10 into the normal score for Apple search term

Comment: Can I do the inverse instead? `text_data:(Apple OR (Apple~2)^0.1)`

Comment: I don't see why not @Howie , it should multiply 0.1 into the score for that clause.